# Set rule in Firebase to get data in about a period

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My app is use Firebase. I've used ChildEventListener to get data.

```
mTaixeReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


          String strTen = dataSnapshot.child("ten").getValue(String.class);
          String strSdt = dataSnapshot.child("sdt").getValue(String.class);
          String strLong = dataSnapshot.child("longtitude").getValue(String.class);
          String strLat = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
          String strDiemden = dataSnapshot.child("diemden").getValue(String.class);
          String strThoigian=dataSnapshot.child("thoigian").getValue(String.class);                                                    

          //Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this,"Toa do: "+strLat+","+strLong,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          double dblLong = Double.parseDouble(strLong);
          double dblLat = Double.parseDouble(strLat);
          //Marker marker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dblLat,dblLong)).title(strTen));

          marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(dblLat, dblLong)).
                  icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(strDiemden)))
                  .title(strTen+"\n"+strThoigian).snippet("Sđt: "+strSdt+"\n Loại xe: "+strLoaixe+"\n Giá: "+strGia));
          Markers.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), marker);
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
         /* if (Markers.containsKey(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
              String strLong = dataSnapshot.child("longtitude").getValue(String.class);
              String strLat = dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(String.class);
              Marker marker = Markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
              marker.setPosition(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(strLat),
                      Double.parseDouble(strLong)));


          }*/
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         /* if (Markers.containsKey(dataSnapshot.getKey())) {
              Marker marker = Markers.get(dataSnapshot.getKey());
              marker.remove();

          }*/
      }

      @Override
      public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
  }

);
```

It has worked well when I set rule like this

```
 {
  "rules": {
     "Taixe":{

    ".read": true,
    ".write": true

   }
  }
}
```

cause I just want to get data in about 10 minutes, so I changed :

```
{
  "rules": {
     "Taixe":{
      "$Taixe":{
    ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",
    ".write": true
     }
   }
}
}
```

and I can not get data. How to get data by ChildEvenListener in this case?

This is my data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firebase read rules are checked when you attach a listener to a location. If you don't have read permission at the location, your listener is immediately rejected.

Knowing that, let's have a look at your rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Taixe":{
      "$Taixe":{
        ".read": "data.child('timestamp').val() > (now - 600000)",
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You're attaching a listener to `Taixe`. But since you don't have read permission there, that listener is immediately rejected.

You're trying to filter data based on security rules. But because the rules are enforced on the listener and not on the child nodes themselves, you cannot use Firebase rules to filter data. This rule is known as "rules are not filters". Searching for that phrase in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters), here [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-security%5D+rules+are+not+filters) or [on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+rules+are+not+filters) will give you tons of results explaining more details.

Comment: I have read and tried to change rules many times, but I still can not get the data that I want. Can you help me fix my rules. please

Comment: As I answered: if you attach a listener to `/Taixe`, you will need to have read permission at that node. So your rules will need to contain: `{ "rules": { "Taixe":{ ".read": true } } }`. And that also means that you then cannot have a rule lower in the tree that automatically hides nodes after X time, since [rules are not filters](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters). It seems that you're trying to combine two features ("hide after X time" and "list all children") that cannot be combined in one list.

Comment: I thought this example is similar to my case. But maybe not  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#structuring_your_rules

Comment: Your rules are great, if you want to "allow reading a child for X time". But that means you can't "list all children". The two requirements cannot be combined in a single list, since [rules are not filters](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+rules+are+not+filters).